# Why is my siamese network learning very well in e.g. 1 out of every 5 runs?

Tags: deep-learning, facial-recognition, accuracy, siamese-neural-network

Why is my siamese network learning very well in e.g. 1 out of every 5 runs? The rest of the time it's not learning and maintains an accuracy of 0.5.

Any explanations? Is the contrastive loss taken in the embedded space to loose of a constraint?

The task is greyscale signature matching.

Additionally, trying the model on facial matching gives a constant 0.5 accuracy, no learning at all - the images are RGB, and maybe it's a higher-order task in general.

Anyways, would appreciate any and all enlightenment in this matter.

P.S. I'm thinking to try a variational autoencoder for the face dataset, where I then use the trained encoder as the siamese network "head".

I would appreciate any guidance or thoughts on this approach as well.

Comment: Are your loss values changing? Check the input, output and loss calculation. Or post some more data here.

Comment: My loss is fluctuating but not steadily growing or decreasing - which makes sense because my accuracy is steadily hovering around 0.5 (random)

Comment: Did you check your pipelines for input and output. Also, if the loss calculation is right? Also, have you set all parameters to trainable?

Comment: Its something with the problem being too hard for the loss or network model

Comment: I think its an implementation mistake or dataset is too easy. I need to see code first. Post it here.

Comment: dataset too hard more likely

Comment: show me the code then

Comment: What's a "greyscale signature matching" task? Can you please provide a link to a reference that describes this task?